# Use any Js Plugin in Umbraco 7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-maps-api-3, jquery-plugins, umbraco7

I'm new to umbraco, and just used a very limited range of Js functions and plugins on that.

So now I need to use some plugin like http://maplacejs.com/ for one of my document types . But it seems doesnt work.

My question is : *is it possible to use any **js plugin** we normally using in HTML , MVC in Umbraco ?*
Is there any difference there?

Comment: Just put your script in template. Template in Umbraco is cshtml page.

Comment: Are we talking about frontend or backend? In the frontend you're not limited in what you want to use since Umbraco is unobtrusive, in the backend you can angularjs 1.1.5 and have to experiment what scripts work without breaking the backend